# Targeting every second tab using Grep and then changing it to nothing

Tags: adobe-indesign, grep

I imported this tabbed text from Microsoft Word into Indesign as shown in the attachment.[image]

I am attempting to replace every second tab in this text into no character ie any tab number that is divisible by 2.

Can this be done with a GREP find change in Indesign please?

Hope this clarifies what I need.

Thankyou!

Comment: I think you forgot to post the image/link to the attachment

Comment: I hope you can see the image. I tried the first suggestion putting   `^t^t`in the find field of the find change dialogue box and then replacing with  ^t but to no avail. Can anyone help?

Comment: "Every second tab" is ambiguous. What you mark in the image is "every last tab" -- and, even more specific, "only that single tab at the end of each line". (This also happens to make the required GREP considerably easier.)

Comment: You don't need any GREP to delete a tab character before an end paragraph character... Just find/replace ^t^p by ^p.

Answer (score 2):

OK, there are 2 tactics that you can take here. You could match what you ask, its a bit tricky it would be easier to match "line ending in tab", which would solve your current situation more easily:

in grep find what:

```
\t$
```

replace by (nothing):

But off course what you ask can also be matched with the GREP:

fid what:

```
(\t[^\t]*)\t
```

"Tab followed by anything not tab put this in replacement group 1 and followed by tab"

replace by:

```
$1
```

"Replacement group 1"

Comment: Sorry maybe I am being misunderstood. I want to target every second character as shown in the image attached. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @JonathanBeech every other on each paragraph?

Comment: Yes please. Thats what I am after

Comment: Excellent. That was just the job thank you. I shall look into using GREP a little more. I have used it in the past in a limited capacity but clearly don't have your GREP chops

Comment: @JonathanBeech I suggest reading [Mastering regular expressions](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596528126.do)